# RegFreeCom not resolving clsid from progid

Tags: windows, regfreecom

So, I have a COM object that I am attempting to load using registration free COM.

I created a manifest for the .ocx, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="assembly1" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <file name="acme.ocx">
        <comClass progid="acme.acme.1" clsid="{5C40FA06-EABB-4633-8938-9394F2C933E1}" threadingModel="Apartment" />
    </file>
</assembly>
```

and saved it as "assembly1.manifest" in my deployment folder.

My application's main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='assembly1' version='1.0.0.0' \"")
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{ 
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  CLSID clsid;
  auto result = CLSIDFromProgID(TEXT("acme.acme.1"), &clsid);
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

When I debug it and check the result from CLSIDFromProgID, despite returning S_OK, the clsid contains a garbage value that is not the same as the clsid specified as the comClass clsid in the manifest. Querying for a different clsid does return an empty clsid and an E_INVALIDCLASSNAME error as the result.

---

glued in a fresh clsid. Tested locally. Still fails.

Comment: Well, it should, that clsid certainly is not "acme.acme.1".  If you post fake info then you can only get fake help.

Comment: Why would the value of the clsid in the manifest matter? There was a lot of cut-and-pasting going on as I was tinkering with this, but this is what my non working sample reduced to.

Comment: Well, this is odd: It doesn't matter what CLSID you put in the assembly manifest for a comClass, the returned CLSID will be different - But if you pass the different CLSID to CoGetClassObject it will in fact create an instance of your object.

Comment: Did anything come of this? What was the garbage value exactly? Was the "garbage" UUID found anywhere else (registry, etc.)?